# Script is being called only once using $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The script is being called only once using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function() { //code here });
```

But it's working just fine using:

```
$('.class').on('click', function() { //code here });

and

$('.class').click(function() { //code here });
```

I need to target the $(document) because I'm appending dynamic elements which can be control later.

This is the exact code I have right now:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', ".dropdown button", function() {
        alert("hi");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
         </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyway I can trigger the script more than once event I'm using $(document) or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. But how about you try this `$('*').on('click', function(){ alert("hi"); });`

Comment: Can you provide also part where you dynamically adding new buttons? You may remove $(document).ready() part and just have $(document).on('click', ".dropdown button", function() {
        alert("hi");
      }); as you adding it to DOM. So for me your example working. And if new buttons goes under div.dropdown, it should work fine.

Comment: I'm going to create a better example. Just one moment. @maximelian1986

Comment: @maximelian1986 The dynamic buttons isn't so much related to this question; rather, a rationale of using `$(document).on('click', ".dropdown button", ...` rather than `$('.dropdown button).click(...` (the latter of which *does* work). If you run the snippet provided, you should see an alert when clicking the dropdown the first time. Subsequent clicks do not trigger the alert (and no, it's not related to the browser blocking multiple popups - the behaviour persists when changing it to `console.log`).

Comment: Ok, now I got your point. Strange thing that without bootstrap links included it works.

Comment: Very strange. Don't understand why it does not work. Now I want to know answer as well. Event still appended to button, div class and button type stay as is...

Answer (score 0):

looks like some kind of bug in bootstrap version that you are using.

I put next refs:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And function firing each button click, however dropdown list looking a bit different, may be there should be some other classes appended or you need to use some manual styling to got your menu styles back.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the Bootstrap JS version `4.0.0` you are using:

I have checked with some other versions like `3.3.7`, `4.1.0`, `4.1.1`, `4.1.2` and `4.1.3` and all are working as expected.

Change

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With any of the mentioned version.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', ".dropdown button", function() {
          alert("hi");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, if I misunderstood your question. But, I think you're asking about how to attach an event listener to the specified button for `click` event *in the context of `window` or `document`*.

If so, then you can use JavaScript's [**`Element.addEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method (**`.call()`** version) to achieve the result, instead of using jQuery!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // document.querySelector('.dropdown button') is same as $('.dropdown button') in jQuery
      window.addEventListener.call(document.querySelector('.dropdown button'), 'click', function() {
        alert('hi');
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
         </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To the downvoter: I appreciate your judgement, but please consider adding a comment as of why you've downvoted the answer or how I can improve it. Thanks!